# Using equation stored in variable Matlab

Tags: matlab, printf, equation, coefficients

I want to use a equation which is stored in variable using inline Function but I am getting an error of 'Check for incorrect argument data type or missing argument in call to function 'coeffs'.
'. Here is the code and the output I want. Matlab

```
syms x;
eq = input('Enter Equation Of Divisor: ','s');
p = inline(eq);
c = coeffs(p);
disp(c);
```

```
> Enter Equation: x-4
> [-4,1]
```

Thanks.

Comment: if you read the Help section of MATLAB, it is recommended NOT to use the inline function, but rather use other anonymous functions.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code:

```
syms x
eq = input('Enter Equation Of Divisor: ');
c = coeffs(eq);
disp(c)
```